# How to wait return mono value function in Mono.flatMap?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

```java
Mono<Student> studentMono = some1();
Mono<School> schoolMono = some2();

Mono<Person> categoryBestPageResponseMono = Mono
    .zip(studentMono, schoolMono)
    .flatMap(data -> {
        Student student = data.getT1();
        School school = data.getT2();
        Person person = Person.builder()
                             .student(student)
                             .school(school)
                             .build();
       return Mono.just(person);
    })
    .flatMap(person -> {
       Mono<PassInfo> passInfoMono = getPassOrfail(person.student.id, person.school.number);

       //pass info is null when first and second get from cache not null
       passInfoMono.subscribe(passInfo -> person.setPassInfo(passInfo));
       return Mono.just(person);
    });
```

In the above source, I always get `null` for `passInfo`.

How can I wait for the `getPassOrfail` operation and put `passInfo` in the `person` in the setter?

Comment: The mono tag has nothing to do with Java. Don't misuse it.

Comment: The code is not compilable on `Mono.just(student)`.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis sorry it was ```person```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the advantage of chaining. Btw. the whole thing can be simplified to a mere snippet:

```
Mono<Person> categoryBestPageResponseMono = Mono
    .just(Person.builder()
            .student(some1())
            .school(some2())
            .build())
    .flatMap(person -> getPassOrfail(person.student.id, person.school.number)
            .doOnSuccess(person::setPassInfo)
            .thenReturn(person));
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't subscribe anywhere throughout your reactive without any needs
2. Don't use `flatMap()` anywhere, I see you're using it for completely synchronous operations and then just doing `Mono.just(...)` in return statement. For synchronous operations there is `.map()` operator
3. Don't access the fields of object directly. They should be private, use getters and setters
4. You don't need to "wait". It is reactive framework, which is asynchronous by it's nature, so just put the proper callbacks on your chain.

```java
    Mono.zip(studentMono, schoolMono)
            .map(data -> {
                Student student = data.getT1();
                School school = data.getT2();

                Person person = Person.builder()
                        .student(student)
                        .school(school)
                        .build();
                return person;
            })
            .flatMap(person -> getPassOrfail(person.getStudent().getId(), person.getSchool().getNumber())
                    .map(passInfo -> {
                        person.setPassInfo(passInfo);
                        return person;
                    })
            );
```

Comment: ```Don't subscribe anywhere throughout your reactive without any needs``` is what mean? How can I choice use subscribe vs doOnXXX. I think that it is same.

Comment: @EdgarHan It is not the same. If you made something working does not mean it is right. Calling subscribe() is justified in cases, when you need to fire some independent background processing, for example. In your case you have step-by-step process, so you assemble your chain, operators are executed within one reactive chain. There's no need to subscribe anywhere in your case

Comment: It looks like subscribe and doOnXXX take a lambda as a parameter and handle it the same. I realize they are different in theory, but in practice they look the same to me. Can you give me an example or a concept to clarify?